# Re-sizing Tumblr photoset width

Tags: html, tumblr

I use a slightly modified version of an old Tumblr theme (The Atlantic #467).

It looks great but photosets are annoyingly small and centered off to the left.

I've looked at soooo many solutions to the Tumblr photoset problem, but they all start with finding and amending the photoset code in the theme's HTML.

Problem is, the word "photoset" occurs nowhere in my theme's code. I'm working more from scratch.

In fact, this is all that's in there vis-a-vis photos is this:

```
{block:Photo}
    {LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}">{LinkCloseTag}
                <p>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}</p>
{/block:Photo}

{block:Quote}
    <div class="quote">
        "{Quote}"
    </div>
    <p>{block:Source}&mdash; {Source}{/block:Source}</p>{/block:Photos}
```

I tried dropping a new piece of code in there and it just made it impossible to actually view or post photosets (not good).

I know this reeks of dumbness. But, hey fellas, ain't that what forums are for?

Answer (score 1):

The basic photoset block should look as follows:

```
{block:Photoset}
    <li class="post photoset">
        {Photoset-500}
        {block:Caption}
            <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
        {/block:Caption}
     </li>
{/block:Photoset}
```

If you can't find `{block:Photoset}` in your theme's code then it shouldn't be rendering Photosets. If you can't find it you can add the `{block:Photoset}` in between the `<ol id="posts">` and an `</ol>`.

In order to customize the (width) style of your posts and your photosets you would have to define CSS rules for the width of the `#posts` id and the `.photoset` class.

For example:

```
#posts {
    width: 500px; /* Recommended width for Tumblr content */
}
.post, .photoset {
    width: 500px;
}
```

The best resource to read is the [Tumblr Docs for custom themes](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes).